# Multi-session in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I organize usage of two sessions in Devise?

My app has some controller to embed it as iframe into another app (using tokens to authenticate). This two apps must be opened at same time and under different users in browser.

Rails 3.2 & Devise 2

Comment: If you don't find anything about devise, you'll find something about how to log in more than one user with warden.

Comment: Unfortunately my app is in production and can't switch to warden.

Comment: Devise - "Flexible authentication solution for Rails with Warden." know your tools™